# How to convert an address in hex string into a byte version of it?

Tags: c#, winforms, arrays, byte

I want to take an address let's say. 0x8402e42d except it is currently in string form which would be just 8402e42d. I want it so I press a button it takes the string out of a textbox which in this case would be 8402e42d, and turn it into 0x8402e42d. I used to know how to do this, but I forgot. Thanks in advance for the help.

I would also prefer to know the easiest way possible of doing this.

Comment: Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311038.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn it into a string with the hexadecimal prefix, you would just add the prefix:

```
address = "0x" + address;
```

To turn the string into a number, you use the `Parse` method:

```
uint n = UInt32.Parse(address, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

(Note: You should parse the string without the hexadecimal prefix `0x`.)

If you want an array of bytes instead of a single numeric value, use the `BitConverter.GetBytes` method:

```
byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(n);
```

Note that the bytes in the array will be placed in the native order, i.e. on a little endian system (e.g. Intel), the least significant byte is first.

You can check the `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` property to find out the endianness of the system, and reverse the array to get a specific endianness:

```
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
  Array.Reverse(data);
}
```